# Finding swapped elements in less than O(n) time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given a sorted array, and two elements one from left half and other from the right are swapped.Find the swapped elements.

The answer is obvious in O(n), but I want to know is it possible in O(log n)?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Peeking into the array at an index i that is not swapped tells you nothing about the swapped elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is guaranteed that the swapped elements are form the different arrays halves ("one from left half and other from the right"):

1. First we can simply iterate over the first half of the array looking for the swapped element in `O(n/2) = O(n)`
2. Then we can use this swapped element for binary search it in the second half of the array in `O(log n/2) = O(log n)`

So, it still will be `O(n) + O(log n) = O(n)`, but in practice it could be a bit faster than the naive approach.

Comment: Actually, it is still O(n) but with a smaller constant.

Comment: You are looking at both halves, so its still O(n).

Comment: Sure guys, I changed the answer to clarify that.

Comment: This answer only provides an upper bound, not a lower bound, of O(n).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible without completely scanning either the left or the right half. All the unswapped elements stay the same as in the sorted array, so they can't give you a clue where to search for the exchanged element, which is the basis for things like the O(logN) binary search.

So there can't be anything better than O(N).

Answer (score 0):

If the swapped elements are mirrored (i.e. the third from the left hand - the beginning and the third from the right hand - the end), then you can do that:

1. Split in half and scan the left half and find the outlier
2. Calculate the index of the outlier in the right side by subtracting 
   `int rightOutlierIdx = arr.length - 1 - firstOutlierIdx`
3. Get the second outlier value by `arr[rightOutlierIdx]`

Should be faster